# [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am sending post request to the server to validate my login data, but when I press login button it show this error:

> [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']

I console log `response` and I got this:

```
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "b69da009-81d6-4391-adf6-99a76a7d5f55", "offset": 0, "size": 145}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "b69da009-81d6-4391-adf6-99a76a7d5f55", "offset": 0, "size": 145}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"connection": "keep-alive", "content-length": "145", "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Fri, 01 Jan 2021 17:03:21 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-powered-by": "Express"}}, "ok": false, "status": 404, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "http://192.168.0.106:3000/login"}
```

And when I console log the values that I input in the `<TextInput` it shows this:

```
[Sat Jan 02 2021 01:03:22.300]  LOG      undefined
[Sat Jan 02 2021 01:03:22.500]  LOG      undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
 constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      loggedIn: false,
      username: '',
      password: '',

    }
  }

  validateUser = async (username, password) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.0.106:3000/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "username": username,
          "password": password
        })
      });
    
      console.log(response);
      const data = await response.json();
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('jwt', data.access_token);
      await this.props.navigation.navigate('adminD')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

And here the TextInput fields:

```
 <TextInput
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                placeholder={'username'}
                onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
                value={this.state.username}
              />
   <TextInput
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                placeholder={'password'}
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                value={this.state.password}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                password={true}
              />
```

Code of server side:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const SECRET_KEY = CONFIG.secret_key;

    findUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('Server error!');
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send('User not found!');
        const result = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user[0].password);
        if (!result) return res.status(401).send('Password not valid!');

        const expiresIn = 24 * 60 * 60;
        
        const payload = { id: user[0].id };
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: expiresIn
        });
        // Check expiration date on the token.
        jwt.verify(accessToken, SECRET_KEY, (errs, data) => {
            console.log(errs, data);
        });
        // To fetch the data shown below, grab the key names.
        res.status(200).json({ "user": user, "access_token": accessToken, "expires_in": expiresIn });
        console.log('Succesful validation of the user.')
    });
});
```

Comment: The server doesn't respond with valid JSON.

Comment: @xehpuk and how to solve this

Comment: Analyze your server code. It looks like the server probably responds with HTML, a 404 Not Found error page precisely.

Comment: You'll need to do a little more debugging of the server. Looks like you got a 404 error which means that the resource `http://192.168.0.106:3000/login` was not found. Maybe it's an invalid path or set up incorrectly. Try accessing it from the command line with a tool like curl: `curl -k -v -X POST http://192.168.0.106:3000/login -d '{"username":"username","password":"password"}'` and see what you get back.

Comment: Simeon's suggestion is very good.  If you don't have cURL, then you can also try `const data = await response.text();`, which will get you the plain text response from the server without JS trying to parse it.  Also try `console.log(response.status, response.statusText)`, which will tell you the HTTP response codes the server gave you.

If you've also written the server code, a very common mistake is that you set up your login page with app.post('login') instead of app.post('/login'), or you set it up with app.get('/login') by mistake.

Comment: @SimeonG i have check that but the path is correct, please check updated question with the code in server side

Comment: @ArtHare i tried `const data = await response.text();` and i got this error ` [Error: [AsyncStorage] Passing null/undefined as value is not supported. If you want to remove value, Use .remove method instead.` and also `console.log(response.status, response.statusText)` and the result was   `404 undefined`

Comment: @SimeonG  may you please tell me how to run the command exactly because it giving `Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'k'.
At line:1 char:6` notice: Curl package already installed

Comment: Sorry about that. -k is only required if you want to ignore SSL checking. Since you're using http here it shouldn't be needed. The -v parameter just does verbose mode so you should be ok to drop that as well. And this all assumes you're running on Linux with at least curl 7.68

Comment: The `[Error: [AsyncStorage] Passing null/undefined as value is not supported. If you want to remove value, Use .remove method instead.` strongly hints that you're using AsyncStorage on your server, and are trying to set an null or undefined item.  This causes an exception, and your server ends up sending an error message back to the client.  My guess is that it's in your `findUserByUsername` function.  Simeon's answer is _also_ correct, as your errors were all going back as non-JSON, so the .json() call was throwing an exception trying to parse them.

Comment: @ArtHare  thanks for replying back i have followed Simeon's answer and im still getting the same error

Comment: @alobe The answer by Simeon may still have a syntax error.  You need `if (!user) return res.status(404).json({error: 'User not found!'});` (note the curly brackets).  In general, all your response types should match the Content-Type header.  I also strongly suspect you have a _separate_ bug involving usage of AsyncStorage like I said above.  Any time your server has an exception and doesn't handle it, you're likely going to get the `Unrecognized token '<'` because express will default to sending an HTML page.

Comment: @ArtHare i have debugged the server code and change it to as how you told me but still getting that error. is there any way to return the exact line where the error occurs ?

Comment: If your JSON parser reports an error, then print out _exactly_ what you are handing to the parser. Usually the problem is that a valid response is JSON, and any error produces plain text.

Comment: @alobe If you're running the server in something like VSCode, you can turn on "pause on uncaught exceptions" and "pause on all exceptions" and it'll break into the debugger as soon as an error is thrown.  Note: With "pause on all exceptions" on, it'll usually break into the debugger for a bunch of spurious ones, so just keep skipping past those.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the server code. I think the problem is that you're not responding with json at all. Change your response for the 404 (and others to this on the server side):

```
if (!user) return res.status(404).json(error: 'User not found!');
```

Comment: Thank you for replying back,, i have tried your way and still same problem  `[Sat Jan 02 2021 02:53:07.490]  LOG      404 undefined
[Sat Jan 02 2021 02:53:07.780]  LOG      [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']`

Comment: The _real_ problem is that server and client _don't agree_. Sending plain text for an error response is fine, as long as the client doesn't try to parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the JSON.stringify here and try making a request

```
body: JSON.stringify({
          "username": username,
          "password": password
        })
```